# How to write custom login function in Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I am building an app which has two types of users, sellers and buyers. Both sellers and buyers have different pages and forms for their registration. I have built the logic for registration of both users and that is working fine.

How can I write the logic for their login. I am confused between those guard and providers. How should I proceed. It would be nice if you share some tutorial or provide the steps to do this. Thanks

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Give us a specific question about guards and/or providers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking requires a lot of documenting the answer and investment of time (which I don't have at this moment). I recommend going though the [Laravel Custom Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards).

Also, to give you a head start, check out this video [Configuring Multi Auth Middleware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8T3MjZPDdI&t=1167s) on YouTube. I was able to build multi-auth after going through this video.